# Como puedo agregar mas de una clase al mismo Modelo en Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, entity-framework

me encuentro con el sig problema, estoy tratando de crear un modelo el cual conlleve multiples clases, pero siempre me da el sig error: TheLender.Models.Prestamista: : EntityType 'Prestamista' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

Un ejemplo seria, el proyecto que se crea por default en Visual Studio 2015, cuando selecionas la opcion de Autenticacion individual, si se fijan les el modelo de Acount tienen muchas clases el cual se pueden utilizar, muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Agrega como estas incluyendo tus clases entidades si estas mapeando desde base de datos revisa que tengas definida tu llave primaria y tu llave foranea en la tabla dependiente. Agrega tu codigo aqui comienza solo con dos entidades.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!